# Modelagem de produto com vários fornecedores e preços diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Em um cenário de controle de estoque onde 1 produto pode ser fornecido por 1 ou mais fornecedores e 1 fornecedor pode conter 1 ou mais produtos, o que fazer na seguinte ocasião:

Produto "X" possui 2 itens no estoque fornecidos pelo fornecedor "A" e tem preço de custo a R$ 23.00 cada e preço de venda de R$ 50.00. O dono da loja para não deixar o estoque acabar, vai e compra mais 100 unidades do mesmo produto no fornecedor "B" com preço de custo a R$ 13.00 cada.

Nesse cenário o lucro em cada venda deste produto fornecido pelo fornecedor A é de R$ 27.00 e adquirido pelo fornecedor B tem um lucro de R$ 37.00 em cada venda.

Minha dúvida é:

Eu não posso simplesmente ir no produto "X" e alterar o preco_custo para o valor do fornecedor "B" pois esse produto fornecido pelo fornecedor "A" ainda não se esgotou e fazendo isso geraria relatórios imprecisos. Existe alguma forma de contornar isso sem ter esse produto duplicado no sistema? Será que esse meu modelo não é o mais apropriado para esse tipo de situação?

[image: Modelagem Produto-Estoque-Fornecedor]

**EDIT1:**

Seguindo o ajuda do @motta removi o preço de custo da tabela de produtos e decidi inserir na tabela produto_has_fornecedor, porém dessa forma toda vez que fizer uma venda terei que fazer um especie de sum na coluna estoque da tabela fornecedor_has_produtos para checar se há a quantidade de produtos comprados em estoque isso seria uma má pratica?

Minha dificuldade levantada anteriormente permanece, ou seja, se um cliente compra 5 unidades do produto "X" a R$ 50.00 cada unidade e eu tenho em estoque 2 unidades desse produto fornecido pelo fornecedor "A" com preço de custo de R$ 23.00 e 100 unidades do desse produto fornecido pelo fornecedor "B" com preço de custo de R$ 13,00 cada unidade, como seria o processo para calcular o lucro dessa venda? e Como seria representada essa distinção de valores de custo do mesmo produto na tabela "venda"?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O preço de venda e de compra tem de estar em tabelas separadas e com data de vigência pois estes valores mudam. Venda pois esttr ligada apenas ao produto pois creio que o preço de venda seja e mesmo e compra ligada a produto_fornacecor.

Comment: @Motta Data de vigência? Mas como saber exatamente quando o produto fornecido pelo fornecedor "A" irá terminar o estoque para então liberar o produto do fornecedor "B" para venda?

Comment: Vigência do preço

Comment: O contador é quem define a baixa do estoque FIFO, LIFO, FEFO, PEPS ou UEPS.

Comment: @Motta desculpe mas ainda não consegui visualizar como inserindo uma data de vigência do preço eu teria esse controle de valor de custo para calcular o lucro, de qualquer forma eu acrescentei uma nova modelagem seguindo uma de suas dicas, mas mesmo assim ainda não consigo o resultado desejado. Será que poderia avaliar esse novo modelo que inseri?

Comment: https://pt.linkedin.com/pulse/saiba-o-que-%C3%A9-fifo-lifo-fefo-peps-ueps-sua-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o    O modelo deve poder rastrear qual foi o preço praticado na compra para isto se precisa do valor praticado pelo fornecedor , isto se tem na nota de entrada , com base nisto você baixa o "estoque" correspondente e verifica o lucro , o contador define qual a forma de "baixa" do estoque.

Comment: Acredito que tenha mais uma questão importante a ser pensada, se o custo do produto pode variar de fornecedor para fornecedor, o preço de venda também não deveria ser diferente, ou seja, mesmo que em um determinado fornecedor o custo seja maior, o preço de venda será o mesmo, acredito que possa melhorar isso na sua modelagem também...

Answer (score 0):

@Vinicius.Silva,

Sei que tem bastante tempo que perguntou sobre a questão do preço de custo do produto, acredito que até tenha encontrato alguma solução, mas segue o que eu faria.

1º sugestão:
O operador do sistema ao selecionar o produto para incluir na venda, deverá também selecionar o fornecedor do mesmo, afinal ele pega o produto para "entregar ao cliente". Assim você saberia, no sistema, exatamente qual produto dará baixa no estoque. Com isso, seus relatórios serão precisos.

2º sugestão:
Utilize a média ponderada para calcular o preço de custo médio do produto.
A média ponderada é calculada multiplicando cada valor do conjunto de dados pelo seu peso. Depois, encontra-se a soma desses valores que será dividida pela soma dos pesos.

Ex. 2 x 23 + 100 x 13 / 2 + 100 = ***13,196***

Eu acredito que esse não é um problema que você resolverá através da modelagem de dados. Em relação a modelagem, eu faria conforme sugerido pelo @motta e colocado por você na edição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]